VBA macro works fine on home machine, but stops on work machine. Also, could I condense this?
I'm very new to coding, but was looking to automate some of my Excel work processes. My work machine seems to run into problems when attempting to filter from largest to smallest, but my home machine does just fine.
It stops at the ".Apply" section and gives me an error

Run-time error '1004'.
Application-defined or object-defined error.

I'm too new to know which it is and how to fix it. I started learning all this a week ago.
I've also had problems with getting the filters to apply correctly on my work machine. I couldn't figure out how to fix that so I'm just removing the initial filters set by whomever originally applies them and letting the macro re-add them. Sometimes the filters are there and sometimes they're not. With my current line to apply the filters it either removes them if they're applied, or applies them if they're missing. I would like it to add them if they're not there, or do nothing if they are there like my home machine does.
My work machine is using Office 16 the same as my home.
Additionally, if anyone has any tips on how to consolidate my code that'd be greatly appreciated as well, but definitely not required. I used the macro recorder all of the conditional formatting sections.
Here is the section it's giving me trouble with (done with the macro recorder):
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("H:H"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

Here is the full thing:
Sub Test()

' Formatting of 1st Row

    Range("A1:Y1").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Bold = True
        .Underline = True
        .Size = 12
    End With

' Selects all cells within the sheet and changes the font to Times New Roman

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"

' Adds filters if Sheet doesn't already have them

    If Not Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode Then Range("A1: Y1").AutoFilter

' Auto Fit Columns then Rows

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Rows.AutoFit

' Adds conditional formatting to the sheet to highlight rows based on cell values and sometimes just the cell

' Conditional Formatting for (Column M) reflecting XXXX

    Columns("A:Y").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$M1=""XXXX"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

' Conditional Formatting for Column M reflecting XXXX2

    Columns("A:Y").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$M1=""XXXX2"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682944
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

' Conditional Formatting for Column K reflecting XXXX

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$K1=""XXXX"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With

' Conditional Formatting for Column K reflecting XXXX2

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$K1=""XXXX2"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

' Conditional Formatting for Column K reflecting XXXX3

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$K1=""XXXX3"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

' Conditional Formatting for Column K reflecting XXXX4

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=$K1=""XXXX4"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

' Conditional Formatting for Column R reflecting a value between 200 & 1

    Columns("R:R").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, \_
        Formula1:="=200", Formula2:="=1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
         .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
         .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
         .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
         .Color = 192
         .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

' Conditional Formatting for Column R reflecting text of "EXP"

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="EXP", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 192
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    'Conditional Formatting for top 15 Oldest Cases & Bold
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
        .Rank = 15
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

'Sort Column H by Largest to Smallest

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("H:H"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Improving Macro Recorder Code: Conditional Formatting and Sort

Note how Top 15 highlights 16 cells because of the duplicates of 40.


Sub ApplyConditionalFormattingAndSort()

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, reference it by its tab name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.
   
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off auto-filtering
    ' Why? Someone might have filtered only a single or a few columns.
    
    ' Set font for whole worksheet.
    ws.Cells.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    ' Note that this takes a lot of time. Maybe you should consider
    ' getting rid of it or applying it only to the range.
    
    ' Clear existing conditional formats.
    ' If you don't do this, you'll end up with duplicate formats.
    ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rg.AutoFilter ' turn on auto-filtering for the range
    
    With rg
        
        ' Format headers.
        With rg.Rows(1)
            With .Font
                .Bold = True
                .Underline = True
                .Size = 12
            End With
            
        End With
        
        ' Autofit columns and rows.
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        
        ' Format data.
        With rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            ' XXXX in M:
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                    Formula1:="=" & .Cells(1, "M").Address(0) & "=""XXXX""")
                .SetFirstPriority
                .StopIfTrue = False
                With .Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                    .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
                End With
            End With
            ' XXXX2 in M:
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                    Formula1:="=" & .Cells(1, "M").Address(0) & "=""XXXX2""")
                .SetFirstPriority
                .StopIfTrue = False
                With .Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682944
                End With
            End With
            ' XXXX,XXXX2,XXXX3,XXXX4 in K:
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                    Formula1:="=LEFT(" & .Cells(1, "K").Address(0) _
                    & ",4)=""XXXX""")
                .SetFirstPriority
                .StopIfTrue = False
                With .Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
                End With
            End With
            With .Columns("R")
                ' between 200 & 1 in R:
                With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=200", Formula2:="=1")
                    .SetFirstPriority
                    .StopIfTrue = False
                    With .Font
                         .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                         .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                    With .Interior
                         .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                         .Color = 192
                         .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End With
                ' EXP in R:
                With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, String:="EXP", _
                        TextOperator:=xlContains)
                    .SetFirstPriority
                    .StopIfTrue = False
                    With .Font
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                    With .Interior
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 192
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End With
            End With
            ' top 15 oldest cases + Bold in H:
            With .Columns("H").FormatConditions.AddTop10
                .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
                .Rank = 15
                .SetFirstPriority
                .StopIfTrue = False
                With .Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .Italic = False
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
                With .Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
                    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Sort Column H descending.
    With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rg.Columns("H"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    ' Sort Column H descending (without 'AutoFilter').
    'rg.Sort Key1:=rg.Columns("H"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub

